# Terraform iterate over list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to replace the 3 indepedent variables (dev_id, prod_id, stage_id), for a single list containing all the three variables, and iterate over them, applying them to the policy.

Is this something terraform can do?

```html
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_policy_document_dynamodb" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:dynamodb:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:table:${var.dynamodb_table_name}"]

    actions = [
      "dynamodb:GetItem",
      "dynamodb:PutItem",
      "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
    ]

    principals {
      type = "AWS"

      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::${var.dev_id}:root",
        "arn:aws:iam::${var.prod_id}:root",
        "arn:aws:iam::${var.stage_id}:root"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I looked into cycles and interpolation, but It seems that 99% of the time the interpolation is done with "count" which only works for the creation of multiple resources (I hope I am not saying a big lie).

For example, I used

```
principals {
   count = "${length(var.list)}"
   identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.list[count.index]}"]
}
```

but that was unsuccessful.

Is there some way of achieving the final goal of replacing those 3 variables by a single list (or map) and iterate over them?

Comment: What do you want the output policy to look like?

Comment: I want the policy to look exactly like in the first code block, that is, it should include the 3 different account ids. However,  I would like to do this with iteration, and not hard-code the 3 accounts... @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given you have the list of account ids, have you tried this?

```
var "accounts" {
  default = ["123", "456", "789"]
  type = "list"
}

locals {
  accounts_arn = "${formatlist("arn:aws:iam::%s", var.accounts)}"
}
```

Then in your policy document:

```
principals {
  type = "AWS"
  identifiers = ["${local.accounts_arn}"]
}
```

I haven't actually tried it, but can't think of a reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, I was not aware of it.
It seams to work as expected, but unfortunately I could not verify it yet because I am getting an error with the policies.
Instead of reading my environmental variable, upon setting the variables on the command line, it treats it as as a string:

I do:
terraform plan \
--var list_account_ids=["${DEV_ID}", "${PROD_ID}", "${STAGE_ID}"] 

and it treats $DEV_ID as the string "$DEV_ID"...

Comment: after correcting the other problems, I managed to run terraform apply with your suggestion (btw, according to the bugs i got its "local" and not "locals"), but now I get a Malformed policy error "aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource".

Comment: typical syntax error. Your answer was great, I will accept it, thank you! @Magd Kudama

Comment: This is the coolest thing I have ever done in TF. Thanks @Magd
I tried and it worked like charm :)